# How can I save my terminal's tabs in memory for the next use?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd, terminal

I would like to keep in memory or settings the set up of my terminals so when I close the IDE I can just come back there later on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the [Restore Terminals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EthanSK.restore-terminals) in vscode.

After the extension installed, you can just create a `restore-terminals.json` file in `.vscode` folder:

```
{
  "artificialDelayMilliseconds": 300,
  "keepExistingTerminalsOpen": false,
  "runOnStartup": true,
  "terminals": [
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "server",
          "commands": ["npm i", "npm run dev"]
        },
        {
          "name": "client",
          "commands": ["npm run dev:client"]
        },
        {
          "name": "test",
          "commands": ["jest --watch"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "splitTerminals": [
        {
          "name": "build & e2e",
          "commands": ["npm run eslint", "npm run build", "npm run e2e"],
          "shouldRunCommands": false
        },
        {
          "name": "worker",
          "commands": ["npm-run-all --parallel redis tsc-watch-start worker"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: does it allow to automatically create the config file based on the currently opened terminals?

Answer (score 0):

Open the command palette by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows/Linux) or Command+Shift+P (Mac).

Type "terminal profile" and select "Terminal: Select Default Profile."

Click on the settings icon located on the right side of the first terminal profile.

Enter the name for your new custom terminal and press Enter.

The settings JSON file will open, displaying something like the following:

```html
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": true,
    "restoreTerminals.keepExistingTerminalsOpen": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "Git",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": ["-l"],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": ["-l"]
        },
        "Git": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "path": "/bin/zsh",
            "args": ["-l"],
            "icon": "git-branch",
            "color": "terminal.ansiGreen"
        },
        "Dotnet watch": {
            "overrideName": true,
            "path": "/bin/zsh",
            "args": ["-l"],
            "icon": "run",
            "color": "terminal.ansiBlue"
        },
    }
}
```

The last two entries represent custom terminal profiles. You can define your own profiles here, specifying color, icon, and other configurations.